# como ocultar y mostrar con css mi parrafo?

Tags: html, css

me gustaria que me ayudaran a ocultar y mostrar mi parrafo con css sea con hover o a darle click al enlace

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Cuál es el párrafo que querés ocultar? Debería ocultarse al hacer `:hover` y después vuelve al estado normal?

Comment: la de <p> Lorem ipsum..........................</p>

Comment: ¿Quieres que no se vea o que además no ocupe espacio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola miro necesitas igual ayuda de JavaScript para lo que deseas lograr te dejo una manera para hacerlo sin ninguna libreria extra

```js
function mostrar(){
  var parrafo= document.getElementById("parrafo");
  if(parrafo.style.visibility==""||parrafo.style.visibility=="hidden"){
    parrafo.style.visibility="visible";
  }
  else{
    parrafo.style.visibility="hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
#parrafo{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close" onclick='mostrar()'>X</a>
                                    <p id='parrafo'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Espero haberte ayudado